# SharePoint 2010 SPWeb.EnsureUser exception

Tags: sharepoint-2010

everyone!

I have the folowing situation.
I'm developing some little search system in SharePoint 2010. I execute SPWeb.EnsureUser for a specific user login name(for test purposes), and I get usernot found exception.

The user totally exists, crawl performed, profile created. If I create simple Console application executing the same code it work fine, AND after that the original code began to work fine too.

But if I run the original code from UserControl method, which belongs to WebPart, I get the situation i've described earlier.

I'll be very thankfull for all kind of answers.

Comment: are you sure you execute the EnsureUser method on the same web? make sure its the RoobWeb too... you might also post some code for us to see

Comment: I'm using such kind of code:

SPSite site = new SPSite("sitecollection");
site.RootWeb.EnsureUser("domain\\user");

Can you tell me if it would be fine if I try to ensure user in the scope of another site collection. Our task is to make cross collection links. So after ensuring I need to get user ID from other site collection.